# Pygame.font.Font.render have TypeError

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, render, typeerror

This is my full programm(it's just for practise):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break
    pygame.font.Font.render('Hello world', 1, (255, 100, 100))
```

And output is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Download\unim.py", line 8, in <module>
    pygame.font.Font.render('Hello world', 1, (255, 100, 100))
TypeError: descriptor 'render' requires a 'pygame.font.Font' object but received a 'str'
```

In game pygame font is optional but it will improve game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your font first e.g.

```
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None,10) # use default system font, size 10
```

you can then do

```
mytext = myfont.render('Hello world', 1, (255, 100, 100))
```

and finally you'll need to blit `mytext` to your surface and update it to display the text.

Have a look at the pygame docs as well on this: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html

EDIT: If that's your complete script, you will need to initialise a display before your event loop:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300)) # create a 300x300 display
```

you can then blit your text to the screen:

```
screen.blit(mytext, (0,0)) # put the text in top left corner of screen
pygame.display.flip() # update the display
```

As the text is static, it doesn't need to be inside your `while True:` loop either. You could display the text first. If you want to change the text based on an event, then this should be handled within the loop.

EDIT 2
In answer to your error message in the comments section, the issue is because some pygame commands are still running after you've issued the `pygame.quit()` command. The reason for this is because your `break` command only breaks the `for event...` loop but you're then still inside your `while True:` loop so the blit command still tries to run.

You could do it this way:

```
import pygame 
pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600)) 
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30) 
mytext = myfont.render('Hello world', 1, (255, 100, 100)) 
running = True
while running: 
  for event in pygame.event.get(): 
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT: 
      running=False

  screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) 
  screen.blit(mytext, (600, 300)) 
  pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

This should work because the main loop depends on `running` being true. Hitting quit sets this to false so the script cleanly exits the `while` loop and then runs the `pygame.quit()` command.

Comment: That's good, but when I leave my program writes:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Download\unim.py", line 11, in <module>
    screen.blit(mytext, (600,300))
pygame.error: display Surface quit

Comment: that's probably because your blit line is after your `while` loop. This means that, when you quit, pygame quits, you come out of the loop and so it executes the next part of the code being that line. Hard to say for sure without your code.

Comment: It's:
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600))
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
mytext = myfont.render('Hello world', 1, (255, 100, 100))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(mytext, (600, 300))
    pygame.display.flip()